# adb devices list empty on Toshiba AS100 tablet

Tags: android

I'm running into an issue with the android SDK where it doesn't recognize devices (Toshiba AS100) under windows, adb devices list is empty:

```
$adb devices                                      
List of devices attached
```

Have tried:

- **Tutorial**: ["Enable ADB USB Drivers for
  Nvidia Tegra based Android Tablets"](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/enable-adb-usb-drivers-for-nvidia-tegra-based-android-tablets/)
- **Setting**: Settings --> Applications -->
  Development --> USB Debugging

According to the tutorial, it works on HTC & Toshiba AC100, but failed on Toshiba AS100. I can find "**Android Phone**" "**Android Composite ADB Interface**" items under "**Device Manager**", but the adb devices list is still empty. Is there an solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check here,

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

My device was not detected in Ubuntu , changed the rules , it worked fine.
In windows , it says USB driver should be installed.
So there might be the issue.

Comment: AS100 uses Nvidia® TegraTM 250, whose usb vendor ID is 0955. I think the tutorial contains all the settings for the rules. But it cannot works...

Answer (score 0):

It works! I removed all the emulators and restored all run configures to default. With a third-party usb adb driver, eclispe finds the device automatically. However,it cannot work when sdk's adb running, and cannot show in devices list. Thanks...